# Chrome Extensions global keyboard listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering whether it is possible to make a Chrome extension, that would listen to an event (such as a button or key press) even if the Chrome browser itself is not focused.

The target would be to, for example, pause a Youtube video when a given key sequence is pressed.

The only problem with that is creating a global listener. Does Javascript or Chrome support them?

Comment: You can only listen for browser provided events. What you are looking for is some bach/exe key logger programm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [documentation for `chrome.commands` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

Commands are keyboard shortcuts; by default, commands are limited to when Chrome is focused, but you can make global-scoped commands.

As a developer, you're limited to making global commands default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[0..9]</kbd>, but the user can reassign the command manually to something else.

Manifest section:

```
    "commands": {
      "toggle-feature-foo": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+5"
        },
        "description": "Toggle feature foo",
        "global": true
      }
    },
```

Then, you can use `chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener` to react to the event.